# Postfix smtpd process not running

Tags: postfix, smtp, debian-jessie

I have a server that runs postfix. I noticed recently that even though the service is running and doesn't report any errors, there are some issues with connections.
For example, `curl localhost:25` hangs.
Comparing with other servers that work as expected, I narrowed the issue down to a process that is not running on the problematic server.

This process is missing:

```
postfix  30173  0.0  0.1  42780  5504 ?        S    12:27   0:00 smtpd -n smtp -t inet -u -o stress= -s 2
```

From what I can tell, the configuration for both servers is identical so I don't understand why this process is not running on the problematic server.

What could be the reason why this process is not running?

All servers run Debian8.

EDIT

On the server with issues, command `netstat -nlp|grep :25` generates output:

```
tcp        0      0 169.254.1.1:25          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      323/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      323/master
```

Whilst on the server where postfix works, is outputs:

```
tcp        0      0 169.254.1.1:25          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15863/smtpd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15863/smtpd
```

/etc/postfix/master.cf

```
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#628      inet  n       -       n       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
# When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
    -o smtp_fallback_relay=
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
```

Comment: Could be that it is not specified in `master.cf`.  Could be that the port is already in use by another process.  Show `netstat -an | grep :25` and `cat master.cf`.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the requested info. It looks like a service named 'master' is using port 25 on the server with problems, whilst the server where postfix runs correctly shows smtpd using the port?

Comment: `master` is normal and launches the other programs like `smtpd` as needed.  Is the firewall blocking port 25? I guess if you are trying `localhost` a provider block is not an issue.  Try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in case of a `/etc/hosts` issue?